# Zend Doctrine2 memcache vs PHP Memcache class

Tags: php, zend-framework, memcached, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to understand the difference between regular Memcache and Doctrine's MemcacheCache.

In my bootstrap I instantiate Memcache like this:

```
    $memcache = new Memcache;
    $memcache->connect('localhost', 11211);
    \Zend_Registry::set("pdc_memcache_core", $memcache);
```

I then have the following code for instantiating Doctrine - this is not the full code as I'm just looking at the cachine:

```
    $doctrineConfig = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();

    $memcacheCore = \Zend_Registry::get("pdc_memcache_core");
    $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcacheCache;
    $cache->setMemcache($memcacheCore);
    $cache->setNamespace("PDC_");
    \Zend_Registry::set("pdc_memcache", $cache);

    $doctrineConfig->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
    $doctrineConfig->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);
```

I then access the cache like this:

```
    if (\Zend_Registry::get("pdc_memcache")->contains($cacheKey)) {
        ...
    }
```

I'm not trying to store Doctrine entities in Memcache - I'm just storing strings and serialised arrays.

Now... is this the correct way to use Memcache with Doctrine? I can see that you use setMemcache to assign the Memcache instance to Doctrine's MemcacheCache... but would I use MemcacheCache for my own stuff? Or should I use the Memcache instance directly?

Would really appreciate some thoughts on this, as I'm confused by how this is supposed to link together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perfectly ok to use the [Memcache Cache of Doctrine Common](https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/MemcacheCache.php), thats also the correct way and you also have some abstraction that allows you to consume any `Doctrine\Common\Cache\Cache` instance. I'm not quite sure you would need that anyway, as you're working with Zend Framework, and you probably could use the [CacheManager](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.cache.manager.html) or it's associated [CacheManager resource](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.cachemanager), which both would give you the advantage to make your caching mechanism configurable.